# Is it possible to get an ID from non-app friends that is reusable when they have the app?

Tags: ios, facebook

My problem is that I want to send something to the user(in my own backend system) who's not using the app along with the invite. This way when they've accepted the invite, there's a message from the user who invited them already in their inbox.

But the ID I can get with /me/taggableFriends and the ID you get from /me/user_friends are not the same. Two users can also have the same Name so that is is not unique.

So the question is there a way to get something that I can use to identify the user before they installed the app and after. So I have something that I can the reuse to identify them again and make the connection to the ID I get from /me/user_friends after they installed the app?

Comment: why not get the user id from backend

Comment: I have achieve this kinda same thing but little differently because we need ID always for everything, using access token get all the friends and user fb id (i send the token to backend and from there got all info from FB) then from services i got all the user and related info, images and id.

Comment: How do you do that exactly? Could you send me a link to a tutorial or something?

Comment: well I had no tutorial but if you use the FB sdk then you will get the access token which you can send to your server or backend for fetching the all related information, your access token will be based on permission so identify your need and ask permission with that, rest is just getting the data from your backend through services

Comment: Are you sure it's possible with v2.0 or the faceboook sdk? Because I can't seem to find any information on how to do that?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBAccessTokenData/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

Comment: So what you're saying is it doesn't work with v2.0? I found a link like this, https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/friends?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN but that gave me the same information I could get on iOS.

Comment: it will work, you can start a session and get access token from session object

Comment: Yes but I'll get the same information on iOS as I would on the web? Which is basically nothing with the changes to the api.